# Can I put a formula within a IF function within Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I want to add an IF formula, so if you see this then 0 but if you don't then do this formula but it keeps saying `#NAME`?

Formula I am trying is

```
=IF(E1=Backup,0,G1-G2)
```

So basically, if the box says backup the figure should be 0 other it should calculate the formula. Is this possible?

Comment: `=IF(E1="Backup",0,G1-G2)`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, you need to modify your formula indeed in order to check for the word "Backup", but there is a case where your formula might in fact be right, as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

As you see, I've given a name to the cell "E2", and that name is "Backup". Your formula now checks if cell "E1" equals the cell, called "Backup", giving the correct result.